# Docker : Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?

Tags: docker

I am new to the world Docker'm having trouble running the first time.
The facility was quiet, however there trying to check existing container, it shows the following message:

> Can not connect to the Docker daemon. Is the running daemon docker on this host?

I've done the start of the daemon to the test reported in the docker documentation I tested is normal and prowling, however to continue the steps displays the message reported above.

Comment: What command are you typing? What is the host OS? What docker info and docker version return? What is the link to the doc you are following?

Comment: Nothing? No comment? No edit?

Answer (score 3):

By default, the `docker` command runs for its own group or root users. Make sure you type prefix the command you're using with `sudo`. Alternatively, you can add your current user to the **docker** group by running `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`.

Source: [the official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/ubuntulinux/#create-a-docker-group).